# R - creating a column of character matrices

Tags: r, dplyr, lapply

Here's my reproducible data frame:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- structure(list(PN = c("41681", "16588", "34881", 
"36917", "33116", "68447"), `2017-10` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `2017-11` = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `2017-12` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), `2018-01` = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), `2018-02` = c(1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `2018-03` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `2018-04` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), Status = c("OK", "NOK", "OK", "NOK", "OK", 
"OK")), .Names = c("PN", "2017-10", "2017-11", "2017-12", 
"2018-01", "2018-02", "2018-03", "2018-04", "Status"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Long story short... two of the steps to get me to the output above were:

`1` *early on in the analysis*

`mutate(n = parse_integer(str_replace_na(n, replacement = 0)))`

`2` *later on in analysis*

```
mutate(
  Status = 
    ifelse(
      (apply(.[, 2:7], 1, sum) > 0) & 
        (.[, 8] > 0), 
      "NOK", 
      "OK"
      )
)
```

Two kind stack warriors @joran and @akrun informed me that I *"created a column of character matrices"* and that's why I kept getting an *"Error in arrange_impl(.data, dots) : Argument 1 is of unsupported type matrix"* error.

In plain English what did I do? I'm the type of guy who doesn't yet understand the difference between an atomic vector and an atomic particle. Can you answer, with something clear and concise?

Or you can just tell me read chapter XYZ in *R for Data Science* or something like that. I'll take that too (maybe in the comments).

Comment: It should be an issue within the `%>%` .  Suppose if you do it outside, it is normal vector `apply(df[2:7], 1, sum) > 0
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE`  Could be some kind of bugs

Comment: I don't see any column of character matrices

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper  If you run the `mutate` and then check the `str` (I am using R 3.4.4`  and `dplyr_0.7.5`)

Comment: it comes from `.[, 8] > 0` , as you have a tibble, not a `data.frame`, it's still a tibble. use `.[[8]] > 0` instead (test `df[, 8] > 0 & apply(df[, 2:7], 1, sum) > 0`, then `df[[8]] > 0 & apply(df[, 2:7], 1, sum) > 0`

Comment: `mutate(Status = as.vector(Status))` fixed the original problem. The issue is I don't have a clue as to what the *problem* was. What/How/Where/Why/When did I create a "column of character matrices"? What is my atomic floating point R Inferno error C##? Heeelllllpppppp. Thanks.

Comment: I'll develop my comment in an answer :)

Comment: a short solution meanwhile is also to just use `if_else` instead of `ifelse`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To behave in the usually expected way, `ifelse` needs a vector of `logical` as a first argument.

What you feed to it here is (replacing the `.` with `df`):

```
(apply(df[, 2:7], 1, sum) > 0) & (df[, 8] > 0)
# which btw we can rewrite more clearly as:
# rowSums(df[2:7]) > 0 & df[,8] >0

#      2018-04
# [1,]   FALSE
# [2,]   FALSE
# [3,]   FALSE
# [4,]   FALSE
# [5,]   FALSE
# [6,]   FALSE
```

This wouldn't happen with a regular `data.frame`, as `df[,8]` would be converted to a vector.

Read `?Extract` about the `drop` argument, `tibbles` behave a bit like `data.frames` do with `drop = FALSE`.

```
head(iris[,1])
# [1] 5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5.0 5.4

head(iris[,1,drop=FALSE])
#   Sepal.Length
# 1          5.1
# 2          4.9
# 3          4.7
# 4          4.6
# 5          5.0
# 6          5.4

head(as_tibble(iris)[,1])
# # A tibble: 6 x 1
#   Sepal.Length
# <dbl>
# 1          5.1
# 2          4.9
# 3          4.7
# 4          4.6
# 5          5.0
# 6          5.4
```

We don't need to get into how it translated to your wrong result, let's just manage to correct the input.

For this you can use `df[[8]]` instead of `df[,8]`, it will always be a vector.

```
df %>% mutate(
  Status = 
    ifelse(
      rowSums(.[, 2:7]) > 0 & .[[8]] > 0, 
      "NOK", 
      "OK"
    )
) %>% str

# Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  9 variables:
# $ PN     : chr  "41681" "16588" "34881" "36917" ...
# $ 2017-10: int  0 0 0 0 0 0
# $ 2017-11: int  0 1 0 0 0 0
# $ 2017-12: int  0 0 0 0 1 0
# $ 2018-01: int  0 0 1 1 0 0
# $ 2018-02: int  1 0 0 0 0 0
# $ 2018-03: int  0 0 0 0 0 0
# $ 2018-04: int  0 0 0 0 0 1
# $ Status : chr  "OK" "OK" "OK" "OK" ...
```

Now the structure isn't problematic anymore.

Another way, that adds only one undercore character to your solution but wouldn't have taught us so much :), is to use `if_else` (from `dplyr` package) in place of `ifelse`. It does the magic conversion internally, that you did in the comments using `as.vector`.

Taking your original code and adding only the magical `_`:

```
df %>% mutate(
  Status = 
    if_else(
      (apply(.[, 2:7], 1, sum) > 0) & 
        (.[, 8] > 0), 
      "NOK", 
      "OK"
    )
) %>% str
# Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  9 variables:
# $ PN     : chr  "41681" "16588" "34881" "36917" ...
# $ 2017-10: int  0 0 0 0 0 0
# $ 2017-11: int  0 1 0 0 0 0
# $ 2017-12: int  0 0 0 0 1 0
# $ 2018-01: int  0 0 1 1 0 0
# $ 2018-02: int  1 0 0 0 0 0
# $ 2018-03: int  0 0 0 0 0 0
# $ 2018-04: int  0 0 0 0 0 1
# $ Status : chr  "OK" "OK" "OK" "OK" ...
```

**Explaination on the error**

```
df %>% mutate(
  Status = 
    ifelse(
      (apply(.[, 2:7], 1, sum) > 0) & 
        (.[, 8] > 0), 
      "NOK", 
      "OK"
    )
) %>% str

# Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  9 variables:
# $ PN     : chr  "41681" "16588" "34881" "36917" ...
# $ 2017-10: int  0 0 0 0 0 0
# $ 2017-11: int  0 1 0 0 0 0
# $ 2017-12: int  0 0 0 0 1 0
# $ 2018-01: int  0 0 1 1 0 0
# $ 2018-02: int  1 0 0 0 0 0
# $ 2018-03: int  0 0 0 0 0 0
# $ 2018-04: int  0 0 0 0 0 1
# $ Status : chr [1:6, 1] "OK" "OK" "OK" "OK" ...
# ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
# .. ..$ : NULL
# .. ..$ : chr "2018-04"
```

Shows that `Status` is a character matrix of 6 rows and 1 column. `arrange` doesn't like that.

**why did you get a character matrix ?**

- `df[, 8]` is a tibble
- so `df[, 8] > 0` is a matrix
- so `(apply(.[, 2:7], 1, sum) > 0) & (.[, 8] > 0)` is a matrix

`?ifelse` says about the output value:

> A vector of the same length and attributes (including dimensions and
>   "class") as test

So `Status` will be a matrix and everything finally makes sense ;).

See also `?dplyr::if_else` for more information.

Comment: Wow. Exactly what I wanted. Would hit the up arrow several more times if I could.